# QList [] operator problem in multi-threaded mode

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have a problem with two following expressions:

QList myList;

Imagine we added some values to myList.

1. QString temp1 = myList.at(0);
2. QString temp2 = myList[0];

When using these two expressions in multi-threaded mode, the second expression causes an error and the code will crash but the first one is working. Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: `QList` is *not* thread-safe.  Simultaneous access from multiple threads will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: when one is crashing while the other "works" it is quite likely that both are wrong. You need to provide a [mcve] before one can say more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.